Laptop cannot boot into any OS, Bluescreens on Windows and Crashes on Linux/Ubuntu
I have a Lenovo Legion 5 that has an AMD Ryzen 7 5800 and a RTX 3070 8gb. I cannot boot into any operating system.
It boots into the BIOS just fine, I am able to alter BIOS settings and what not. Start up time is flawless.
SSD is empty as i bought it brand new however is recognised by the BIOS.
It has 2x8gb ram sticks.
It boots into the windows installation media but bluescreens as soon as it does. It spirals for 1-2 minutes before bluescreening.
Any live os like Linux or Ubuntu just crash for random reasons, can never boot into any OS.
Have memtested the ram sticks, no errors. The SSD was brought brand new as well. Have tried putting the installation media and live os's on multiple different USB sticks, and they always boot on other laptops.
Any ideas?

If you're experiencing crashes on multiple OSes, you are dealing with a hardware issue. Memory isn't the only thing that could be bad. You should begin swapping out other components to isolate the issue.

Hey, what else do you think has gone wrong? The BSOD error is CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED on windows. It is a laptop so i am quite limited as to what I can do ;/

Can't say. That's a pretty generic error. You start with the easy things, things you CAN replace, and work your way onward.

If you've made bootable media, such as Ubuntu Linux, multiple ways, using Rufus, UNetbbotin, etc., and have set BIOS to allow alternate boot correctly, then likely it's one of many possible hardware problems that causes the issue. You might remove SSD, as it could be part of the cause.

How long have you had this laptop? Is it under warranty?

Lenovo Legion 5 is a pretty new machine so it would probably have UEFI instead of BIOS. Have you tried to upgrade it and its bootloader?

Hey all. I appreciate everyone taking time out of their day to try and help me. I have noticed that the drive disconnects itself before the windows bluescreen, so I am troubleshooting by using different USB sticks and software to create the ISO. @juandev It is updated to the latest BIOS version. @ Jarmomanada It is but i'd like to avoid RMA if its something i can fix at home.

There are so many things to check and to do. Personaly I would start from:

Test with One RAM Stick
Remove the SSD and boot from Live USB
Disable the discrete GPU
Try disabling Secure Boot in the BIOS
Disable Fast Boot

If the system boots successfully, put the SSD back

Ensure that the controller is set to AHCI mode instead of RAID or IDE in the BIOS

